# newtxmath package disrupting blackboard bold greek characters

Tags: packages, blackboard

I'd like to use some sort of blackboard bold capital Delta in a large TeX file. In the past I've used to code displayed below to typeset it, but when I include a new package "newtxmath,newtxtext" that I'm using for some special characters, it changes the display from the usual blackboard bold Delta to a normal boldface Delta. Blackboard bold numerals 1, 2, ... are unaffected.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}%\normalfont\Nearrow
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}

%special blackboard bold characters
\newcommand{\bbefamily}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{bbold}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\textbbe}[1]{{\bbefamily #1}}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbe}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}

\def\DDelta{{\mathbbe{\Delta}}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbbe{1}}
\newcommand{\2}{\mathbbe{2}}

\begin{document}

$\1$ and $\2$ and $\DDelta$ and $\mathbbe{\omega}$

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on?

Bonus question: I'd love to also be able to typeset a blackboard bold lower-case omega.

Comment: I get the same output (apart from the text font, of course) with or without `newtx{text|math}`. You never get a blackboard bold omega; for that something more would be needed.

Comment: That's strange. For me, when those packages are commented out, I see a capital blackboard bold Delta, with the left-diagonal edge duplicated. When those packages are included, I see a boldface Delta, with the right-diagonal edge thicker than the other two.

Comment: Update: By checking error logs produced when I compile, I think the issue with the blackboard bold Delta has to do with some font resizing or something with the newtxmath package. When I remove that package but keep the newtxtext one, the font resizing doesn't happen for some reason, so the blackboard bold  Delta looks like it should. I guess that, plus the \usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol} suggested below, solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}` in the preamble.
Hollow omega (or any other minuscule Greek letter) can be typed with `\bbomega`. [For hollow epsilon, use `\bbespilon`.]

Comment: Thank you. I'm very happy with the \bbomega and appreciate the warning about "espilon".

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but more of an explanation:

There are two issues:

1. by default `\omega` is defined not to react to math alphabet (contrarily to  `\Delta`). This is the default situation without any package and is not changed by your loaded packages.
2. in font `bbold` in `U` encoding (see file returned by `kpsewhich Ubbold.fd` for the specific tfm filenames), there is no omega at the default location occupied by `\omega` (slot 33), rather it contains there a blackboard bold exclamation point.

Check with:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}%\normalfont\Nearrow
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}

%special blackboard bold characters
\newcommand{\bbefamily}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{bbold}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\textbbe}[1]{{\bbefamily #1}}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbe}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}

\def\DDelta{{\mathbbe{\Delta}}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbbe{1}}
\newcommand{\2}{\mathbbe{2}}

% check in the (long) compilation log lines containing XXXXXXX to find
% some info on this modification to let \omega obey math alphabet:
\typeout{XXXXXXX Current meaning of \string\omega: \meaning\omega}
\count255\omega
\mathchardef\omega\numexpr \count255+"7000\relax
\typeout{XXXXXXX New meaning of \string\omega: \meaning\omega}

\begin{document}

$\1$ and $\2$ and $\DDelta$ and $\mathbbe{\omega}$

% for testing
% \ttfamily
% \meaning\omega

% \meaning\Delta
\end{document}
```

which produces:

> [image: Blockquote]

Playing with `pdflatex nfssfont` (but see *(*)* next) one finds the blackboard omega in slot `"7F` (127). You can obtain it in your set-up with `\mathbbe{\mathchar"717F}` but it would be more appropriate to define a Symbol Font rather than a math alphabet.

> [image: Blockquote]

*(*)* Last thing: <strike>it is not clear what you mean by "bold" as your math alphabet uses `m` not `b` or `bx` for the series.</strike> Isn't there a package to use font `bbold`? Ah yes, `texdoc bbold` tells me there is package `bbold` and the contents of `bbold.sty` is actually copied with a renaming in your code. There is no boldened variant it seems.

<strike>You could use package  `bm` to bolden the symbols, but there are surely better alternatives.</strike> Anyhow, "blackboard bold" was obviously not used to mean "bold blackboard bold" ...

Comment: Package `mathbbol` mentioned @SammyBasu's answer provides indeed the needed interface. It does `\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}` and `\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbomega}{\mathord}{bbold}{"7F}` among other things. Had I read that I could have spared contributing this slightly off-the-mark answer...

Comment: After trying 3 other solutions, this is the only one that I could generalize to work outside of math mode.